# VBA Multiple Optional Function Parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write the [SWITCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) in VBA for my coworker who has Excel 2013. I feel that my VBA is strong enough to code this function once I set up all my function parameters. However, I'm not sure how to have an unlimited number of optional parameters in a function (similar to `*args` in Python). How can I set up a function so that it may have an unlimited number of optional arguments?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optionalargumentstoprocedures.aspx.

Comment: Do you really need an "unlimited number" of parameters? And if so, can you give some use-case with expected outputs? (this is part of [ask]).  It's possible this is an X/Y problem, and perhaps rather than re-creating the `Switch` function in VBA, you could simply use the `Select Case` operator in VBA, which is more or less equivalent to the [c# `switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch). But if you need to take an arbitrary set of pairs from the user, maybe you do need to recreate Switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ParamArray`, e.g.

```
Public Function TestSum(ParamArray a())
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        TestSum = TestSum + a(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

An interesting question, here's my attempt at replicating the `Switch` functionality.

You will need to use a `ParamArray` argument:

> Optional. Used only as the last argument in arglist to indicate that the final argument is an Optional array of Variant elements. The ParamArray keyword allows you to provide an arbitrary number of arguments. It may not be used with ByVal, ByRef, or Optional. ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/function-statement))

Revised, thanks to the comments with @TinMan, we no longer use a Dictionary so this will be compatible with Mac OS without further tweaks.

```
Function FSwitch2(ValueToMatch As Variant, ParamArray ValuesToMatchAndReturn())
' example of replicating the Switch function available in Office 365, etc.
' https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e
Dim i As Integer
Dim retVal As Variant
Dim default As Variant

If (UBound(ValuesToMatchAndReturn) + 1) Mod 2 <> 0 Then
    ' if the array is not evenly sized, assume the last argument is the default value.
    default = ValuesToMatchAndReturn(UBound(ValuesToMatchAndReturn))
Else
    ' Otherwise, default to #N/A error if no match.
    default = CVErr(2042)
End If

For i = LBound(ValuesToMatchAndReturn) To UBound(ValuesToMatchAndReturn) Step 2
    If ValueToMatch = ValuesToMatchAndReturn(i) Then
        retVal = ValuesToMatchAndReturn(i + 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

FSwitch2 = IIf(IsEmpty(retVal), default, retVal)

End Function
```

Comment: I was actually have a little fun with the post.  I was, however, thinking of a hard coded `Switch()` statement.

Comment: A VBA `Switch()` statement uses an index.  I don't think that you actually need a `Dictionary` because you only need to find a single value. Simply return the value when found.  Or an error is not found.  In any case, there really isn't much need to optimise something like this. +1

Comment: @TinMan You don't *need* a dictionary, you could do this with a pair of Arrays, or a pair ArrayLists, and I think you *could* do it within a Select Case if you defined all 124 optional pairs of value/resul;t, but it gets *really* messy when needing to check parameters exist. The problem with doing a straight *index* against the `ParamArray` is that you won't differentiate the *values* from the *results* and could end up with some wrong results that way.

Comment: This is the best that I can do in under 5 minutes [fswitch.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18Yy0nCxJbFbpAO8-2ekWhN7qwokdNTpV)

Comment: @TinMan yes that might work. The `Step 2` is what I was overlooking when I was doing the same thing...

Comment: @TinMan no, I can't. I spoke to soon :D

Comment: No worries, I posted a complete answer too soon.  The only reason that I was able to write it so fast was that your answer is quite well structured.  Copy, paste, refactor..life of a VBA Hack...

Comment: @TinMan shooot. I even had `Step 2` in my code for the same reason. But I was over-thinking it ...